# How to find objects in storyboard/nib that are of a specific colour in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to find all objects that are within a storyboard/nib in my Xcode project that contain the `groupTableViewBackground` colour. If I type `groupTableViewBackground` into search it doesn't come up with anything. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you want to do with those objects?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't find a property value with the `Find` command but you can open your storyboard with a text editor or clicking `open as -> source code` like in this image:

[image]

Then find in it all `groupTableViewBackground` occurrences.

I hope you just have to change the color to all the views otherwise you can use the view id to find then in the IB.